# Prove or disprove: $g(x) = x^2 - 2x + 1$ monotonically increases for $x > 1$.

Tags: proof-verification, algorithms, proof-writing

I know I can compare $g(x)$ and $g(x+a)$ where $x$ is in the region of interest and $a > 0$, and to expand out the algebra to show that $g(x+a)$ always equals or exceeds  $g(x)$ but I'm not entirely sure what approach to take. Help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use the fact that $x^2-2x+1 = \left(x-1\right)^2$, and that $f\left(y\right)=y^2$ is increasing for $y>0$, and using $y=x-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the derivative of the function: $g'(x)=2x-2.$ We can see that $\forall x>1$, $g'(x)>0$ by computing the second derivative $g''(x)=2$. This implies that $g$ has rate of change greater than $0$ for all $x$ greater than $1$ because $g'(1)=0$. So $x>1\implies g'(x)>0$, that is, this function is strictly increasing. It is also monotone increasing.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $x > 1$.  Let $a > 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
g(x + a) - g(x) & = (x + a)^2 - 2(x + a) + 1 - (x^2 - 2x + 1)\\
                & = x^2 + 2ax + a^2 - 2x - 2a + 1 - x^2 + 2x - 1\\
                & = 2ax + a^2 - 2a\\
                & = 2a(x - 1) + a^2
\end{align*}
Since $x > 1$ and $a > 0$, $2a(x - 1) > 0$ and $a^2 > 0$.  Hence, $g(x + a) - g(x) > 0$, from which you can conclude $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing when $x > 1$.